# Swift ViewController Background getting black with alpha

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uibackgroundcolor

I'm calling a ViewController as popover when the user presses a button. The View should have black background with alpha 0.5.
But the View is shown as that for a second, than the whole background turns black without alpha. Any idea why?

Thats my popover call:

```
let popOver = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popOver") as! ViewControllerPopOver
    popOver.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    self.present(popOver, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'm trying to set the background color in popovers `viewDidLoad()` function with following code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that set `modalPresentationStyle` to [`overCurrentContext`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/1621507-overcurrentcontext) instead of `popover`.

```
let popOver = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popOver") as! ViewControllerPopOver
popOver.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(popOver, animated: true)
```